# Uploading a file in django database in a specific root with diferrent folders everytime

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I´m trying to upload file into database, but when i want put the function uoload to and i want to that function store the file in a root with the data the user submit in the for, for example year, course, section, I get that information and the file they uploaded I want to store in that subfolders, the code that I´m using only store the data in the Media_root, but not in the carpets how can I do in order to store the  files in the subfolder I want. I'n my model document I store the information of the document, like  the autor, the title,etc.

```
class File(models.Model):
     titulo_file=models.ForeignKey(Document,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,verbose_       name='Título de la Tesis')
     file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True, upload_to=generate_path)
```

Here the function I use to upload the file, Int only works to store the file into a folder with it´s same name.

```
def generate_path(instance, filename):

      path =os.path.join(instance.file.name,filename)
      return path
```

In my view, after the user submit the information, I use a `os.path.join`, that  do the path with the information submited like this:

```
year/course/section
```

I want to send that path to my generate_path and store in that location the file, I tried with session but it doesn't work, what can I do?

models.py

```
class Year(models.Model):
    year_number=models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)

class Section(models.Model):
    numberSection=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

thopic_documents=(
       ('CS','CS'),
       ('SE','SE'),
       ('IS','IS'),
       ('IT','IT'),
    )

class Document(models.Model):
     title=models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
     thopic=models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=thopic_documents, default=None,null=True)

class Historial(models.Model):
      id_section=models.ForeignKey(Section,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      title_document=models.ForeignKey(Document,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

Comment: Can you post the model that contains the `year`, `course` and `section` attributes? Is that the `Document` model, or some other model?

Comment: Is some other model

Comment: Thanks. So if you have a `Document` how would you lookup the `Section`? Is that possible? Can that be done through `Historical` or another model somehow?

Comment: I look through the section with the Historical, and Section have the infotmation of the model course and year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the year/course/section you need to be able to navigate from a `File` to a `Section`. However, the many-many relationship that exists between `Document` and `Section` through `Historical` makes it unclear how you would do that. Which `Historical` would you choose?

It may be better if `File` was linked directly to `Historical`:

```
class File(models.Model):
     titulo_file=models.ForeignKey(Historical, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,verbose_name='Título de la Tesis')
     file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True, upload_to=generate_path)
```

If that was the case, you could then implement your `generate_path()` such as:

```
def generate_path(instance, filename):
    section = instance.titulo_file.id_section
    year = section.year.year_number
    course = section.course.name
    return os.path.join(str(year), course, str(section.numberSection), filename)
```

To do the same thing with the model as it currently stands, you would have to do something like this:

```
def generate_path(instance, filename):
    section = instance.titulo_file.historical_set.first().id_section
    year = section.year.year_number
    course = section.course.name
    return os.path.join(str(year), course, str(section.numberSection), filename)
```

That example uses `historical_set.first()` to get the first `Historical` linked the `Document`. Maybe that would be ok, but otherwise you'd need to know which `Historical` to use.

Where a file with the same name is uploaded and you don't want to overwrite it, you could implement your own [storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-file-storage/):

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class UseExistingStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def save(self, name, content, max_length=None):
        if not self.exists(name):
            return super().save(name, content, max_length)
        return name  # Don't save when the file exists, just return the name
```

Then reference the `UseExistingStorage` from your `File` model.

```
file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True, upload_to=generate_path, storage=UseExistingStorage())
```

Comment: But I need to have the model Document and atached to it I need to have the file model. In Document the title it´s the pk, and historiacal have the title and the id of the model Seccion. I need to keep my models like that, theres no way to do what I want with my currently models?

Comment: Every `Document` can have many `Historical`s so with your current models you would need to know which `Historical` to use in order to get the `Section`. Would it be the most recent `Historical` or a specific one? If you know that then you could use your model as it currently stands

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example of how you could do it with your current model, and the problem you would face identifying which `Historical` to use.

Comment: Sorry for just answering, but I'm getting this error `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Comment: If I want to get the last historical, Instead of first, I put lastest()?

Comment: Yes you can, and you may be best to pass `id` such as `latest(id)` unless there is a specific date field on the `Historical` that you could pass instead.

Comment: I´m getting this problem, I don't know why. `object of type 'int' has no len()` in `ntpath.py in splitdrive, line 115`

Comment: I think the `year` and `sectionNumber` need to be converted to a string when building the path. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: One more thing, If I alredy have the file in my computer and only want to put the link in my server, in other words, i don´t want to uploaded it again into the root I have do it with the funtion generate_path, I only want to get the root of the file that is alredy in that location and linked it with the database,using the same model that I use before

Comment: I think for that you could write your own [storage class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-file-storage/#writing-a-custom-storage-system) which would check whether the file already exists (the name it receives is the name from `generate_path`). If the file exists, it just returns the name (does not overwrite, just creates the link) otherwise it creates the file normally. I have not tested it so you may have to play with it yourself - but hopefully it gives you an idea. See updated answer.

Comment: I wil have to mention where could be the file if it exists ? I mean I have to give the path year / course / section in order for my session storage to look there and check if the file I want to upload exist or not, am I right ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to build the filename yourself. The name that is passed to `if not self.exists(name)` is already the name from `generate_path`

Comment: I missed the `self` attribute from the `save()` signature - updated the answer. Make sure you pass `name`, `content` and `max_length` to `super().save()`

Comment: It doesn't work, it don´t save me the link in the database, I only want to have the link of the file that alredy exists in the path that it search.For example, I alredy have a repository of file that I want to put in django database, also If other user have other files they can uploaded it at the same path that the existing files are. But I don´t know hoe to make the database to only get the path of the files that alredy exists and save it in the database but dont save a copy of it